# Installing Git via NodeJS in Windows 8

Tags: node.js, git, github, windows-8

I am running NodeJS in Windows 8 building a HTML app. Tried to create my first git repo via NodeJS for my App. Started this off with "git init" but this failed.

Can I install Git for use on Windows via Node using the command line or do I need to download and install Git in the Windows environment?

Comment: A 2s search: https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Comment: You don't need NodeJS for using Git !

Answer (score 1):

You need to go [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and download and install Git for Windows.

Also your statements in your question about installing Git via Node make no sense at all. Your question should be titled "Can I install Git via the command line on Windows?" and has no relation to NodeJS.